# Calculating karma from upvotes/downvotes on a user's posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User and Post model and am using the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem (which gives me a 'votes' table) to upvote/downvote a post. I want to assign karma to each user, where karma is the number of upvotes a user has gained from all his/her posts minus the total number of downvotes.

Currently I have this instance method on the User's model to calculate karma:

```
  def karma
    count = 0
    self.posts.each do |post|
      count += post.upvotes.size - post.downvotes.size
    end
    return count
  end
```

I don't think the above is very efficient with a run time of O(2n), because for every post two additional database queries are required, one for the upvotes, and one for the downvotes.

Any ideas on how to combined the above into a single query, or otherwise make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only about efficiency, such design is not good in terms of OOP. The User model considers too much beyond its scope. Karma is something belongs to user and should not be tied in anything else.

A better approach is to separate "Karma" from Post.

```
# Add a "karma" column
$ rails g migration AddKarmaToUser

# Or use a dedicated table
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :karma
```

Then, use Controller or service object to change karma. I'll cover Controller here for simplicity. Do not use Model callbacks as that is cross models.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def upvote
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.upvote # pseudo API of acts_as_votable
    current_user.increase_karma
  end

  def downvote
    # ...
    current_user.decrease_karma
  end
end

# Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :karma

  def increase_karma(count=1)
    update_attribute(:karma, karma + count)
  end

  def descrease_karma(count=1)
    # ...
  end
end

# View
user.karma
```

Comment: What do you mean, "...such design is not good in terms of OOP. The User model considers too much beyond its scope." Is it bad design because I am trying to access votes which do not belong to the User model but rather the Post model, or is it because I am accessing posts which is defined by a relationship and is not an actual attribute on the Users table? Is user.posts okay but user.posts.first.votes bad? or are they both not good?

Also, currently I have a separate votes_controller. Is it more restful to have the votes action in the posts_controller like you demonstrate above?

Comment: Steve, for your first statement, yes, `user.posts` is okay, but `user.posts.first.votes` is not good. This user's hands are too long :) He touched something not belonging to him. For votes, I think putting them in PostsController is more natural. Even if you have more votes for others say Comment, you can put votes for comments in CommentsController.